# Creating new dynamic menu including BP links

Tags: menus, buddypress

Perhaps I have missed something fundamental, but I am attempting to include the various dynamic menu items included with BuddyPress and other add-ons to my primary drop-down menu.

For example, the Twenty Eleven WP theme has a tall header with a drop-down menu beneath the header.  This menu can be manipulated via the Appearance->Menus option in wp-admin.  BuddyPress adds its own menu items to the admin bar at the top of the page but does not include these links in the drop-down menu below the header.  I would like to remove the admin bar completely and relocate all dynamic links to the drop-down menu.

I have already created a custom menu in the `functions.php` file:

```
function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
  array( 
  'header-menu' => __( 'Nav Menu' )
  )
 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

And this menu is loaded in the `header.php` with:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

I am able to add individual links to this menu using the `wp_nav_menu_items` function, but cannot seem to be able to replicate the dynamic menu structure created by the `bp_nav` functionality based on user.

Does anyone have ideas on how I could relocate this functionality?  Or perhaps am I looking at the menu structure incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't have specific code to suggest, it seems like it would be possible to create something along the lines you mentioned by using a [custom Nav Walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function) and generating buddypress-specific links with the `$bp` global (which you can learn more about here → http://codex.buddypress.org/developer/the-bp-global/).

You could alter `$output` in the custom Nav Walker based on checks against `$bp`, if it even exists.